# Suppose G has order 35 and |X|=17

Tags: finite-groups

**Suppose G has order 35 and |X|=17.
Suppose that no point a in X is fixed by all g in G.
Find the number of orbits and the size of each orbit.**

I am not really sure how to go about this, the example I have been given in lectures is not of this form at all.

Comment: What's this example? Maybe there is some analogy that you can't notice at first glance:) What do you know about sizes of orbits?

Comment: It's about the colourings of a beads of a neclace.

Comment: Emily, what do you know about sizes of orbits of a $G$-action, when $G$ has $n$ elements?

Comment: I'm not sure. Something to do with the index?

Comment: I meant exactly what mixedmath wrote: that the size of an orbit is a divisor of the size of the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to using the [Orbit-Stabilizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit-stabilizer_theorem#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma) Theorem, which says in short that $|Gx||G_x| = |G|$ for all $x$.

Orbit-Stabilizer tells us that the size of each orbit $Gx$ is a divisor of the size of the group $G$, so that in this case each orbit has size $1, 5, 7,$ or $35$. We clearly can't have $35$, since there aren't $35$ elements in the set. Similarly, we can't have $1$, because that would mean that every element of $g$ fixes that element.

So all the orbits are of size $5$ or $7$. But every element is in some orbit (namely, its own orbit). So we have a diophantine equation $5a + 7b = 17$ for positive $a,b$. There is exactly one solution, which is $a = 2, b = 1$.

Thus there are $3$ orbits, $2$ of size $5$ and $1$ of size $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take a look at the class equation (or orbit stabilizer theorem). Use partitions of 17 and the fact that the size of the orbits divides the order of the group.

Comment: http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-2/class-equation/class-equation.html